# How to fetch the value out of VertX Future object

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am unable to retrieve value out of the Future object. Below is the code for reference

```
Future<Configure> conf = getLatestVersion(request);
Configure cc = conf.result();
float previousVersion = cc.getVersionNo();
```

Here is the implmentation of the getLatestVersion(request)

```
public Future<Configure> getLatestVersion(Configure request) {
        Future<Configure> result = Future.future();
        configRepository.getLatestVersionNo(request).setHandler(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                result.complete(res.result());
                System.out.println("==result from db =="+res.result());
                System.out.println("== getVersionNo ="+res.result().getVersionNo());
            } else {
                result.fail(res.cause());
            }
        });
        return result;

    }
```

In the SOPs i am able get the values from the `result.result()` and the `result.result().getVersion()`, but after returning the result from this method to the above caller i am not able to fetch the values.

What i want to achieve here is i need the `Configure` pojo data out from the `Future<Configure>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `onComplete()` callback (or `setHandler()` in earlier versions):

```
Future<Configure> conf = getLatestVersion(request);
conf.onComplete( res -> {
  if( res.succeded() ){
    Configure cc = res.result();
    float previousVersion = cc.getVersionNo();
  }
} );
```